# Why need to shift elements of ArrayList to the left after removing an element?

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist, null

As far as I know, here are steps to remove an element in an `ArrayList`.

1. No need to do anything with the target element
2. Iterate along the array from 1 after the deleted element, to the last element
3. Copy each element into the location 1 before it
4. Set the last element to `null`

Why don't just set the element we want to remove to `null`? That takes only one step.

Could anyone explain the merit of above scheme? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of the list like a book with writing on all the pages. Removing an element is like removing a page from the book. What you're proposing is more like erasing what's on the page - it's not the same operation at all. (If your particular use case is fine with the size of the list staying the same, etc, then just call `list.set(index, null)` - but that's not what's required in most cases.)

Comment: It is the difference between remove and replace. In the later case you would replace the element with a null object.

Comment: @DaisyShipton that would be good as an answer ;-)

Comment: So if `null` in a list means the element at that index is "removed" then what if I want to _actually_ store `null` as an element? how do you distinguish a removed element and an _actual_ `null` element?.

Comment: you are aware that `ArrayList` has  some `remove` methods - **you** do not have to do all these steps! (these are kind of required for arrays) -  and `null` is a valid element to put into an `ArrayList`, why ever the programmer needs it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why don't just set the element we want to remove to null?

"setting" an element to null is not *removing* an element it's *replacing* an element.

There's another issue with that approach, if `null` in a list means the element at that index is "removed" then what if I want to actually store `null` as an element? how do you distinguish a removed element and an actual `null` element?

Leverage the `remove` methods in the [`List<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) API, don't try to reinvent the wheel as they're as good as they can get.

Comment: 'déjà vu'  ! [:-) an correct answer IMHO to "Could anyone explain the merit of above scheme?"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger wow with the French characters as well :). just wanted to point out another problem that may arise with setting elements to null.

Comment: I just *noted* that I have just commented that on the question (and Nikolas answer)

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I realized that I was confused between "replacing (with null)" and "removing". It seems the scheme described in my question is what called "remove" in common. Understood it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Because these are not the same (let's remove the `"c"`):

- `["a", "b", "d", "e"]`
- `["a", "b", null, "d", "e"]`

There is a big difference between the removal and the replacement:

- The removal changes the indices, removes an element and shifts (affects) the remaining ones. This also changes the size of the list. Ex. the element `"d"` is accessible at the index `2` (moved from the `3`).
- The replacement replaces the item and keeps the indices of the elements and the size of the list remains unchanged as well. Ex. the element `"d"` is accessible at the index `4` (unchanged).

Comment: _"There is a big difference between the removal and the replacement."_ to the point. +1.

Comment: maybe also "allow `null` elements in the list" or "how to distinguish between wanted `null` and deleted `null` placeholder (or so)"

Comment: `null` is always allowed in the list (by the definition of List). There is no way to distinguish between the wanted and the unwanted `null`. If you want to keep the indices, you can replace "c" with a "fake object" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern.

Answer (score 1):

...because that's how Lists work. Many usecases need this dynamic sizing behaviour, so Java [has an interface for the List concept](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is one of several implementations of List, [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is another.

We already had the behaviour you're describing, [the Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) - so where you need that behaviour you would use say a `String[]`.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayLists are just like arrays with one difference - they are resizable(it does not matter in this example).
Consider the following array: `[ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4]` , where ref1:4 are references to some objects. It means that they do not contain the object itself, they only point to the object. Now, if you want to delete ref2 for example by declaring it null that means that it won't point to any object now (`ref2 = null`) but that does not mean that the reference itself dissapeard.Your new array(ArrayList) will be `[ref1,null,ref3,ref4]` now. You see? There is a difference between replacement and removal....